# How to checkout repo inside the docker in GitHub action

Tags: docker, github-actions

Scenario:

I have built an image and uploaded into ECR.

Now in GitHub action, I would need to pull that image and run some command against the git repo.

However, it seems like  actions/checkout is not able to be executed inside docker due to write permission error.

Wonder if there’s a way to solve this problem.

Comment: please include details like the code you're using, how to reproduce the error, and solutions you have attempted.

Answer (score 6):

Checking out a repository using `actions/checkout@v2` works for me, but only if I switch to a user with sufficient privileges for the default directory, for example `root` or `1001` (the user used by GitHub Actions):

```yaml
jobs:
  my-job-name:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: ghcr.io/<whatever>
      options: --user root
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

This seems to originate from my custom container image and not from the action.

If you don't want to run as `root`, there is a related [issue](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/211), stating that you can also first get ownership of the directory before checking-out the repository.

Comment: Adding `options: --user root` worked for me.